# Multiline pattern match and delete lines - sed/awk/grep

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

Input.txt

```
-------
Database alias = ABC
Node name = node01
Hostname = hostnode01
Service name = 12345
-------
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Database alias  = PQR
Node name   = node01
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Database alias  = XYZ ......
```

Expected Output

```
-------
Database alias  = ABC
Node name   = node01
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Database alias  = PQR
Node name   = node01
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Database alias  = XYZ ......
```

Idea is to remove the Duplicate Values of Hostname & Service Name if repetative
or you can say
Remove lines between `'-------`', if there are 2 lines in between.

Tried using sed with Multiple Match, but not getting desired o/p

```
sed '/-------/{$!N;/\n.*Hostname/d;}' Input.txt
```

Comment: Well, you're really close there... You need to pull in two lines when you encounter a match and then delete, otherwise just do nothing. It's easier if you negate the condition (assuming gnu sed here, based on your code): `sed '/-------/{$!N;/\nHostname/!b;N;d;}' infile`

Comment: @don_crissti is right (as usual), except I'd suggest to make it work on POSIX `sed` as well: `sed -e '/-------/{$!N;/\nHostname/!b' -e '$!N;d;}'`

Comment: I presumed that the duplicate entries might not be consecutive ...

Answer (score 2):

GNU **`awk`** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         RS = ORS = "-------\n";
         pat = "^Hostname += ([^ ]+)\nService name += ([^ ]+)\n$";  
     }
     NR == FNR{ 
         if (match($0, pat, a)) { items[a[1], a[2]]++ } 
         next 
     }
     match($0, pat, a) && (a[1], a[2]) in items \
     && items[a[1], a[2]] > 1{ next }1' inout.txt input.txt
```

The output:

```
-------
Database alias = ABC
Node name = node01
Hostname = hostnode01
Service name = 12345
-------
Database alias  = PQR
Node name   = node01
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Database alias  = XYZ ......
-------
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a job for `sed` (you shouldn't depend upon the duplicate entries being consecutive). Use `awk`:

1. Set the record separator to the regex `^-+$`.
2. Use an associative array, where the index is a concatenation of HostName and ServiceName. For any record read, place the record in the array only if it does not already exist.
3. At the end of processing the file, print out all elements of the array, formatted into separate lines, with your `----` delimiter lines.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplicity of your sample dataset is not typical of the actual use case, but given the triviality of the example you post, `grep` alone would suffice:

```
$ grep --no-group-separator -A4 '^Database alias' input.txt 
Database alias = ABC
Node name = node01
Hostname = hostnode01
Service name = 12345
-------
Database alias  = PQR
Node name   = node01
Hostname    = hostnode01
Service name    = 12345
-------
Database alias  = XYZ ......
```